# Updating a control outside the UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

So I have a `UserControl` with some cascading `DropDownList`s on it.  Selecting from list 1 enables list 2, which in turn enables list 3.  Once you've made a selection in all three lists, you can move to the next page.

The `DropDownList`s are all inside an `UpdatePanel`.  But the "Next Page" button is outside the `UpdatePanel`.  That button should be disabled until all three lists have a selection, and then it should be enabled again.  But since the button is outside the `UpdatePanel`, it doesn't update when I make selections.  (**Edit**: The "Next Page" button is on a page that also contains the `UserControl`.)

I know one way to resolve this:

```
var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(dropDownList1);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(dropDownList2);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(dropDownList3);
```

This ensures a postback when any dropdown list is changed, so that the button can update.  But if I do this, I might as simplify by getting rid of the `UpdatePanel` in the first place.

Is there another way, through some clever JavaScript or something, that I can update a control outside an `UpdatePanel` without having to give up Ajax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you not add a update panel around the "next page" and then add a trigger to the dropdownlist updatepanel for triggering the next page update panel?

Just throwing out ideas, without actually having tried it :)

Comment: This is the closest to what I had to do.  Instead of a trigger, I simply had to call a method on the main page (casting this.Page) to set the Next button properly.  I also had to RegisterPostBackControl on the Next button to get it to work inside the UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 12):

Place an UpdatePanel around the next button and create a trigger for each of the dropdowns so that it fires an async postback. Ex:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dropDownList1" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dropDownList2" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dropDownList3" />
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can upddate a control outside the update panel by placing it into update_panel2 and saying `update_panel2.update()`.

Note the `UpdateMode` of the UpdatePanel must be set to `conditional`for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

This would ideally be done in javascript, with a server-side validation check in the click event handler.

A quick jQuery example:

```
//assuming the dropdowns all have the css class "cascade"
$('select.cascade').change(function() {
  If ($('option:selected',this).length == 3) {
    $('input[id$=btnNext]').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```